# Removing a line from hosts file that contains name that starts with specific id

Tags: regex, sed

Attempting to automate hosts file clean up and generation with multiple docker instances.

Entries in hosts file will look like:

```
172.19.0.5 srs_develop_memcached-1_1 # docker-hosts.php
172.19.0.8 srs_test_memcached-1_1 # docker-hosts.php
```

I was using `sed` to remove lines that end with `# docker-hosts.php`.

Now I need to be more specific and target the lines that end with `# docker-hosts.php` and also have the instance name that starts with `srs_test` or `srs_develop`.

What I started with was:

```
sed -i '/# docker-hosts.php\$/d' /etc/hosts
```

Now I need to be more specific, based on the docker instance I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed -i '/.*srs_develop.*# docker-hosts\.php$/d' /etc/hosts
```

The regex matches lines that contain "srs_develop", and ends with "# docker-hosts.php".